# How do I run numerous Python programs with Perl in parallel?

Tags: python, perl, parallel-processing

At the moment I have a Perl script that runs a python program a number of times, it takes a while as each program is run sequentially, is there a way to run the python programs simultaneously?

Here is the code

```
use Cwd;
$curdir=getcwd;
chdir("../python");

for (my $i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
    $cmd="python myCode.py";
    system($cmd);
}

chdir($curdir);
```

The python code takes about 10 seconds to run, and this way the programs run one after the other, it takes a while and I'd like to run them in parallel.

Is this possible and how?

Separately, if it is possible, would it also be possible to limit how many can run at once? I was thinking up to 4 since I have 2 cores with hyper-threading however the python code usually takes about 19% of a CPU so maybe up to 20 at once.

Comment: Why not do this in Python? That way you can save the `fork()`ing of the Python processes.

Comment: I'd rather it be in perl, My code actually has more to it, this is a simplified example, after running the python code a few times a few perl scripts are ran in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

python itself have multithread management. Perl invoking python code would be unnecessary, although perl have multithread modules as well. You can refer to [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) for more details.